# Swift unable to open dependencies file during build

Tags: swift

the Error: unable to open dependencies file (.../GameTrackerMTG-
fugrsvwgzcfzrrapewbryumhfcaq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GameTrackerMTG.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/
GameTrackerMTG.build/Objects-normal-asan/arm64/CounterView.d)

The file it complains is sometimes CounterView.d sometimes AppDelegate.d, sometimes any other swift file in the project, it changes if I make any changes in any of the files or reopen xCode. The problem started appearing after I upgraded xCode to 14.0.1

I have deleted dependencies folder, changed location of it, made new project, recreated all of the files in new project, including core data model and changed the projectname. I have not added any external dependencies etc. I am out of ideas and can't find anything more to try by googling :)...

Answer (score 0):

Change the Target Build Settings -> Swift compiler - Code Generation -> Optimization Level to No optimization for Release. This solved the problem for me[Build Settings update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJC4A.png)